# Is this bounty text phrased well enough, so people will udnerstand what the requirements are?

Tags: discussion

> While most answers seem more or less verisimilar, I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require phrases like "The factors I find[...]" or "I'm pretty sure[...]", to be correct. So I'll award the bounty to that answer that provides 1 of the following: a) A refference to a official or at least resonable informed source, supporting the answer. Or b) an documented elaboration supporting that the answers elements are accurate AND which notes also why there are no other influences possibly affecting the results.

This is the text, I'm intended to put as additional bounty information onto that post: [Factors for max CP at a particular trainer level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274148/88641)

Can you guys help me with eventually improving it?

Comment: Someone has commented with a [possible dup](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273607/which-pokemon-have-the-highest-cp-cap) - does that not answer your question? The table provided in an answer there seems pretty useful.

Comment: @TimMalone: The mainproblem with that list is that it is contradicting with what I have observed so far. Thats why I want to finally get supported informations. But thanks anyways since this still si a better place to put the bounty on.

Comment: I believe there is a pre-written bounty reason which says something along the lines of 'looking for answers supported by official/credible sources'. That should work perfectly for you.